# Where should grub be installed, MBR or root ? default desktop use-case

Tags: grub2, hard-disk

I had purged grub and then re-installed, while reinstalling it asks with the help of a curses GUI

[image: Configuring grub-pc where to install grub]

As can be seen it asks where to install. While by default, I always use MBR, is/could there be a use-case to use grub at root instead of MBR ?

Comment: Yes, it can be useful with virtualization hypervisors such as VMware ESXi.